# Salesforce System Amin cloned profile

Tags: profile, administration, user, sales-cloud, clone

I cloned the System admin profile and realized it does not have the login as user option right beside a user's name. I created a delegated admin group and added the profile with the enable login option checked on the setting and still the cloned profile cannot login as another user. Does anyone have any similar problems or answers to this issue? Attached are the two different views of the admin and cloned profile. [image]

[image]

Comment: As per [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_delegate.htm&type=5) "Delegated administrators can:Log in as a user who has granted login access to the administrator." Have you checked if end user has granted login access?

Answer (score 0):

The ability for an admin to "Login As" another user is a powerful feature in Salesforce, and there are several things to consider when setting it up.

**Here are some recommendations:**

- Ensure the "Enable Admin to Log in as Any User" setting is enabled. Go to Setup → Security Controls → Login Access Policies. Here, you'll find the "Administrators Can Log in as Any User" option. If it's not enabled, even System Admins won't see the "Login As" option.
- Even if you cloned the System Admin profile, double-check the profile permissions. Ensure the "Modify All Data" permission is enabled. This permission is typically required to use the "Login As" feature.

Hope this helps!